# Problema de conexión PHP con MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

tengo varios dias intentando conectar mi base de datos con php, el servidor es xampp la version actual, y me da este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'tienda '@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\tareas\tarea23\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tareas\tarea23\index.php(3): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'tienda ', 'password', 'tiendabd') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tareas\tarea23\index.php on line 3

he hecho varios intentos buscando por google y no lo he conseguido,
1- tengo el root con pass y el config.inc.php con su password,
2- tengo el usuario tienda zodos con los privilegios para poder acceder a la tabla tiendabd
3- instale el xampp como administador y luego lo abri como admin y tenia mas error q si lo hago todo normal, solo tengo una cuenta en este windows y es el usuario administrador.
4- intente igual con el usuario root acceder pero tampoco lo logre.

pruebe algunos comandos por consola algo que le daba pribilegios a todos, pero tampoco
tambien probe agregarle una linea al my.in.php, este funciono pero cuando paras el mysql y vuelves a correrlo no se establecio como encendido mas, muchos errores q no logre solucionar.

el codigo es:

```
    <?php
require_once('conexion.inc.php');
$conexion = new mysqli("$servidor", "$usuario ", "$passwd", "$basedatos");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Error al establecer la conexión con la base de datos: ". mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}


?>
```

y pagina conexion:

```
    <?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$basedatos = "tiendabd";
$usuario = "tienda";
$passwd = "password";
?>
```

nose un poco desesperado con este problema, no me deja avanzar en mis estudios,
Les agradeceria mucho una ayudita chicos

Un Saludo

Comment: Pues, yo te recomiendo que vuelvas a dar un a revisar los accesos que tiene el usuario tienda. Desde el Workbench y prueba los permisos del usuario; si como dices tienes los accesos de administrador, entonces primero ingresa como admin y cambia todos los permisos de tienda.

Comment: nada, que opinas de instalar el xampp en mis documentos o algo que no necesite ese privilegio de administrador, es que no lo se XD

Comment: El mensaje de error es inequívoco: el usuario `tienda` no tiene permisos de acceso. Prueba a conectar desde la consola con el usuario administrador de MySQL y ejecuta esta instrucción: `SHOW GRANTS FOR localhost@tienda;` Verás los permisos que tiene el usuario `tienda` realmente, y si no tiene permisos para esa BD tendrás que otorgárselos.

Comment: @A.Cedano, muchas gracias, hice el login con root, y este es el resultado, tiene todos los prestigios,  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tiendabd`.* TO `tienda`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: Intenta ahora entrar desde consola con el usuario `tienda`, parece entonces que es la contraseña lo que está mal.

Comment: @A.Cedano, si se conecto por consola


# mysql -h localhost -u tienda -p
Enter password: ********
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 23

Comment: Es muy extraño entonces. Lo único que se me ocurre es que tengas dos instalaciones de mysql y que tu PHP esté apuntando a la instalación que no es.